# Logic - Proof with Quantifiers

Tags: logic

The question reads: (∀x)(∃y)(x + y ≥ 3) x is an integer and y is a natural number.

Let x be an arbitrary integer.
Now I'll need to find a y such that x + y ≥ 3.
I'll take y = 3 - x.

Now, this is where I'm stuck. I'm thinking, if x ≥ 3, then my chosen y will not be a natural number anymore. Or am I not getting something here? Would like some hints to guide me in the right direction, thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\geq 3$ then just use $y=1$. If $x<3$, use $y=3-x$ as you say.